# Qual as principais vantagens da Api ser RESTful?

Tags: api, rest, restful

Em relação ao modelo de maturidade de API REST, o nível 2 consiste em "HTTP + Recursos + Verbos".
Quais as vantagens em relação ao nível 1 e zero? Além de organizar a API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou citar algumas vantagens abaixo:

1. **Padronização da API**

- Divisão de funcionalidades por recursos
- Padronização de URIs e parâmetros

2. **Melhor aproveitamento de recursos do protocolo HTTP**

- Convenção e utilização de recursos baseadas em documentação ([RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) por exemplo)
- Unificação de funcionalidades de recursos em uma única URL com a derivação dos métodos HTTP para cadastro, alteração, exclusão, etc...

3. **No último nível, temos o aproveitamento do HATEOAS como forma de apresentar uma trilha de recursos que pode ser seguida com o retorno da API**

- Com isso podemos incluir links que sejam interessantes ao recurso, como links para outras páginas, para o próprio recurso, para recursos relacionados ao recurso, entre outras
- Também é embasado por documentação ([RFC5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988) e um [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-03))
- A utilização de links facilita ao integrador ter acesso e navegabilidade a recursos derivados de forma prática e rápida.

Alguns exemplos relacionados aos pontos mencionados acima.
Para o primeiro caso, podemos aplicar padronização da seguinte forma:

```
* https://minhaapi.com/getCar?id=2
* https://minhaapi.com/getCustomer?id=5&name=nullptr
* https://minhaapi.com/getManufacturer?id=5

Separando por recursos teremos:

* https://minhaapi.com/cars/{id}
* https://minhaapi.com/customers/{id}?name=nullptr
* https://minhaapi.com/manufacturers/{id}
```

Ainda aproveitando o gancho para o item 2, com o melhor aproveitamento dos recursos teremos o seguinte cenário:

```
* GET  https://minhaapi.com/getCars
* GET  https://minhaapi.com/getCar?id=2
* POST https://minhaapi.com/createCar
* POST https://minhaapi.com/updateCar
* POST https://minhaapi.com/deleteCar

Utilizando os verbos HTTP

* POST      https://minhaapi.com/cars
* GET       https://minhaapi.com/cars
* GET       https://minhaapi.com/cars/{id}
* PUT/PATCH https://minhaapi.com/cars/{id}
* DELETE    https://minhaapi.com/cars/{id}
```

E agora aplicando HATEOAS no retorno dos recursos, teriamos a possibilidade de implementar navegabilidade ao nosso conteúdo do response:

```
* GET  https://minhaapi.com/cars/5

HTTP 200

{
    "car": {
        "id": "5"
        "model": "Fusca",
        "manufactor": "VW"
    },
    "links": {
        "_self": { "href": "https://minhaapi.com/cars/5" }
        "manufacturer": { "href": "https://minhaapi.com/manufactors/56" }
        "similar": { "href": "https://minhaapi.com/cars?related=fusca" }
    }
}
```

Você também pode incluir links para ajudar na paginação, quando a consulta de um endpoint de listagem é paginada, um exemplo pode ser visto [nesta chamada](https://dev.juno.com.br/api/v2#operation/listCharges) da API da Juno.